# How to get the information from "About Phone"

Tags: android

I want to read the information from the "About Phone"

In a device I can navigate "Settings --> About Phone"

How can i read that information prgramatically. I want to know which API will provide this information.

I want to know information like:

Firmaware Version.
BaseBand Version.
Kernal Version.
ROM Build number etc.

I have tried with the Build class, but I am unable to get to know the above values.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get some of the information as static String constant from [Build class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)

Answer (score 3):

Firmware version: `android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;`

Kernel version: `System.getProperty("os.version");`

Have not find a way to get baseband version and ROM build version though

Answer (score 0):

check out

android.telephony.TelephonyManager